# What kind of neural network am I using? How can I build a specific kind of network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I'm going through a tutorial for tensorflow with keras and at one stage you build the neural network model using the code below.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(1)])
```

I'm aware that there are different kinds of neural networks such as CNNs and RNNs which are better suited for different tasks. However, how do I relate the architecture built here to what kind of model it is?

Also if possible, if I know what type of model I want to build how does that relate to how I build the keras model?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have designed a simple ANN architecture. Anyhow if you want to build CNN architecture(Refer https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/) RNN architecture(Refer https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/). My suggestion would be better to have an understanding of compete architecure of any version of NN before you apply.